# issue - creating a directory with gradle not working

Tags: java, shell, gradle

I have the following `build.gradle`:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'java'

task filter(type: Copy) {
    def subdir = new File(project.buildDir, "subdir")
    println("subdir: "+subdir)

    if( !subdir.exists() ) {
        println("creating subdir")

        if(subdir.mkdirs()) {
            println("succeeded in making folder")

            if(subdir.exists()) {
                println("folder exists")
            } else {
                println("folder does not exist")
            }
        } else {
            println("failed to make folder")
        }
    } else {
        println("folder exists already")
    }
}
```

After downloading the wrapper using `gradle wrapper` I then run:

```
/tmp/test $ ./gradlew clean filter
subdir: /tmp/test/build/subdir
creating subdir
succeeded in making folder
folder exists
:clean
:filter UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.121 secs
```

Which seems to indicate everything went okay.  However, when I double check I get this:

```
/tmp/test $ ls -l /tmp/test/build/subdir
ls: /tmp/test/build/subdir: No such file or directory
```

*Notes*:

- This is on MacOS Mavericks.
- The executing user is able to create the directory at the shell.
- There is sufficient disk space.

Please advise what I might be doing wrong here with Gradle that fails to create the directory, but that Gradle indicates it was successful?  Any troubleshooting tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Why do you manually create the directory, and from/to where do you want to copy (after all you declared a `Copy` task)?

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I would be interested in finding out the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Might be the copy task has done nothing, is  "UP-TO-DATE".

```
13:21:40.045 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFile
sTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':filter' as it has no source files.
```

I think this is due to a Copy task requires a from and into.

Try creating a non copy task like,

```
task filter() << {
    def subdir = new File(project.buildDir, "subdir")
    println("subdir: "+subdir)

    if( !subdir.exists() ) {
        println("creating subdir")

        if(subdir.mkdirs()) {
            println("succeeded in making folder")

            if(subdir.exists()) {
                println("folder exists")
            } else {
                println("folder does not exist")
            }
        } else {
            println("failed to make folder")
        }
    } else {
        println("folder exists already")
    }
}
```