# Can gradle create META-INF, WEB-INF folder and web.xml automatically?

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

I am new to gradle. I would like to start a web application with gradle. The version i am using is v3.1

For now, i only add apply plugin: 'war' in the build.gradle file.

i use war plugin, but it does not create META-INF, WEB-INF folder and web.xml after running ./gradlew build.

do i need to manually create those folders and file or gradle has a way that i do not know to create them automatically?

Comment: May be this is the answer you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241895/issue-creating-a-directory-with-gradle-not-working

Answer (score 3):

The [Gradle specification of War plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html#sec:war_default_settings) answers your question:

> The default behavior of the War task is to **copy the content of src/main/webapp to the root of the archive. Your webapp directory may of course contain a WEB-INF sub-directory, which may contain a web.xml file. Your compiled classes are compiled to WEB-INF/classes. All the dependencies of the runtime configuration are copied to WEB-INF/lib.**

Comment: but why there are no WEB-INF/classes sub-directory, WEB-INF/web.xml file after running ./gradlew build. Do i need to manually create them first and then they will be included in the war file?

Comment: I expect that you have no source code under src/main/webapp to put into WEB-INF/classes. You have to manually create web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled this https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-web-applications/.

The guide mentioned:

> There are two options for defining web application metadata. Prior to version 3.0 of the servlet specification, metadata resided in a deployment descriptor called `web.xml` in the `WEB-INF` folder of the project. Since 3.0, the metadata can be defined using annotations.

I think Gradle encourages the use of annotations, so Gradle doesn't automatically create the `WEB-INF` folder and etc.